# Echo name instead of value from database

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry I am back with another simple question. I tried searching for the answer but I do not think I am wording my search right.

I am wanting to echo a name instead of the value. I am trying to learn php/mysql and I am coding a simple admin login page that gets redirect to 1 or 2 pages based on the users role.

Here is what I have for my inputs

```
<select name="role">
  <option value="1" selected>Admin</option>
  <option value="2">Super Admin</option> 
</select>
```

Well when I go to a page that list the "admins" I want it to display either

Super Admin or Admin

Right now, it is echoing 1 or 2.

```
<td><?php echo $role;?></td>
```

Again, I am sorry if this has been asked before, I did look but not sure I was wording it right. Just trying to learn as I go.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where / how are you storing that information? You probably need to query the database to get the correct name with the value.

Comment: I have it being inserted into the database.

Comment: I mean, where is the relation between numbers 1, 2, etc. with the corresponding titles stored? That's where you need to get it.

Comment: A form saves values (either "1" or "2") to the role variable in form, the `"Admin"` or `"Super Admin"` are only labels, they aren't sent with the data in the form. You'll have to do an if statement, `if $role == "1"` etc for admin, or send the strings instead of numbers: `<option value="admin" selected> ..<option value="super_admin">...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well without knowing the greater extent of your application a simple solution would be having role names stored in an array, example:

```
<?php //declare somewhere globally, early on in your script
$role_names = [1=>"Admin",2=>"Super Admin"];?>

<td><?php echo $role_names[$role];?></td>
```

This would be a simple solution to your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set output based on $role variable, for example:

```
if($role == 1){echo "admin";}
else if($role == 2){echo "super admin";}
else {echo "user";}
```

This is just an simplified example . Check what are real values stored in your db and based on that do what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

*$role* will contain the *value* attribute from the option not the value displayed to the user. If you want to display *Admin* when you echoing, you need to change *value* attribute in your select.

```
<select name="role">
  <option value="Admin" selected>Admin</option>
  <option value="Super Admin">Super Admin</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options for your select box have the values set to 1 and 2, those are probably the values that are being saved into your database that you are then echoing out.

Set the option values to admin and super admin and it should save the values to the database when you submit your form then you can echo the correct role.

Or you could add an if statement like

```
If ($role == 1) 
   echo "admin";
else
    echo "super admin";
```